# Rails escape_javascript creates invalid JSON by escaping single quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, escaping

The escape_javascript method in ActionView escapes the apostrophe `'` as backslash apostrophe `\'`, which gives errors when parsing as JSON.

For example, the message "I'm here" is valid JSON when printed as:

```
{"message": "I'm here"}
```

But, `<%= escape_javascript("I'm here") %>` outputs `"I\'m here"`, resulting in invalid JSON:

```
{"message": "I\'m here"}
```

Is there a patch to fix this, or an alternate way to escape strings when printing to JSON?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call .to_json on a string and it will be escaped properly e.g.

```
"foo'bar".to_json
```

Comment: This does not work if the string is HTML for example and has double quotes in the string for example.

Comment: @margusholland - not true - .to_json handles escaping double quotes perfectly

Comment: `"foo'bar".to_json` outputs `"foo'bar"`

Comment: Nope, sorry. My returned JSON is clearly breaking because of any number of single quotes. `to_json` does not handle them. Rails 4.1

Answer (score 7):

I ended up adding a new `escape_json` method to my application_helper.rb, based on the `escape_javascript` method found in `ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper`:

```
JSON_ESCAPE_MAP = {
    '\\'    => '\\\\',
    '</'    => '<\/',
    "\r\n"  => '\n',
    "\n"    => '\n',
    "\r"    => '\n',
    '"'     => '\\"' }

def escape_json(json)
  json.gsub(/(\\|<\/|\r\n|[\n\r"])/) { JSON_ESCAPE_MAP[$1] }
end
```

Anyone know of a better workaround than this?

Comment: I don't know much about Rails. But is there any way you can use `render :json` as described at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: That works for converting objects, but not sure about strings.  I'll look into it...

Comment: Only thing I've found so far that's worked. Not sure why to_json decides to escape quotes with a single backslash instead of double but that had me for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

May need more details here, but JSON strings must use double quotes. Single quotes are okay in JavaScript strings, but not in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I added an example for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

I had some issues similar to this, where I needed to put Javascript commands at the bottom of a Rails template, which put strings into `jQuery.data` for later retrieval and use.

Whenever I had a single-quote in the string I'd get a JavaScript error on loading the page.

Here is what I did:

```
-content_for :extra_javascript do
  :javascript
    $('#parent_#{parent.id}').data("jsonized_children", "#{escape_javascript(parent.jsonized_children)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Already there is an issue in github/rails
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8844

Fix to mark the string as html_safe

```
<%= escape_javascript("I'm here".html_safe) %>
```

or even better you can sanitize the string

```
<%= sanitize(escape_javascript("I'm here")) %>
<%= escape_javascript(sanitize("I'm here")) %>
```